# PhpStorm 9 env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I am using csscomb to prettify my `.scss` files. All was fine until I upgraded to PhpStorm 9.

csscomb runs without any problem from the terminal, but PhpStorm seems not to recognize node's path. When I run the command I get:

```
env: node: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

Any idea how to configure this ? Tried to edit path manually but failed.

Answer (score 11):

To fix this you need to symlink the nodejs executable to node

`sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/local/bin/node`

If you installed node with **nvm**

`sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Saved my life, thanks. [ Working with Webstorm, installed current node version with nvm ]

Answer (score 1):

Restarting phpstorm fixed the issue. Still wondering why...

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

because not found nodejs, open & edit the lesscss program code first line, tell him where is the nodejs.

Comment: an explanation could go a long way

Comment: not a nice solution, but will do. Still not clear why /usr/bin/env node fails when ran by phpstorm, although when you run it directly it works